# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ApiException: The session timeout is not within an acceptable range

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I get above exception in my consumer with kafka 0.9.0.1.According to this thread[1] i do not see the "group.max.session.timeout.ms" property in the server.properties file.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ApiException: The session timeout is not within an acceptable range
```

Any clue?

[1]http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.kafka.user/12426

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a server-side config in kafka that restricts the maximum timeout value:

```
group.max.session.timeout.ms
```

The default value is 30000ms if it is not set.

This is located in "/config/server.properties".

Set it to a higher value than your consumers timeout and you will be fine.